# In five minutes that door is going to open, and a man... will tell me I am free to go

Tags: dialogue, fargo-tv

The following contains information about the final episode of Fargo Season 3.

In the final scene of Fargo Season 3 Varga has been detained by homeland security, and is being interviewed by Burgle.  The two exchange some pleasantries, and Varga says:

> No, that’s not what’s going to happen. In five minutes that door is going to open, and a man you can’t argue with will tell me I am free to go, and I’ll stand from this chair, and disappear into the world, so help me, god.

I'm certain this is a reference to another film, where a detective successfully detains the criminal, but is then told to let him go by a superior.  What is the referenced film (series)?

Comment: I heard this recently in another TV show..at least along **very similar lines** of not verbatim. Not sure if it's a reference or just common dialogue.

Comment: Well that sucks... I'm sure I've heard that sentence before (it kind of seems to be something recent)  and I never watched Fargo. I hate myself for not remembering where... Seems to me that it was something from a powerful bad guy or something related to knowing the future. Maybe _The Edge of Tomorrow_ that I watched recently... I would have to watch it again to be sure, though.

Comment: Maybe on one of those super hero series: _Gotham_, _Daredevil_, and so on... Looks like something a villain who runs the prison would say to the good guy who caught him.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe it's from the "[Lord of War](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0399295/)" movie ([alternative link for the europeans](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTK8torOylM)).

Comment: could you tell us how you found this, and possibly provide a transcript of what's said in the clip?

Answer (score -3):

I think you're thinking of American Made with Tom Cruise. The trailer was released this year and there is a point where he is caught and he states something similar.

Comment: The *trailer* was released this year? I don't think *Fargo* would be referencing a film that isn't even out yet.

Comment: Since I have heard it also in a recent TV episode (which, unfortunately, I cannot recall), I'm pretty sure this verges on a *trope*.

Comment: @F1Krazy good point... didn't even think about this question in relation to Fargo. I just knew the quote sounded familiar and I remembered hearing something similar in the trailer of American Made.

Comment: @ColeL afraid I've never seen it, so don't think it's that, thanks for trying though